# iOS | UIKit | Error sizing the avatar images to the image container

Tags: swift, uikit, message

I am working on a Chat View that fetches data from an endpoint, it has a key that gives me an avatar URL, after converting that data and displaying it on the custom chat cell, it doesn't take the height and width of the image view in the custom cell ( which I have the constraint to 32x32)

I have added the code for Table View Controller and Table Cell Controller along with reference images for the view and cell layout.

Custom Chat Cell
[image]

Screen error
[image: Error]

Chat Cell Code

```
class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var userMessage: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        // set message corner radius as 8px and border
        userMessage.layer.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) // set the background color
        userMessage.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // set the corner radius
        userMessage.layer.masksToBounds = true // this will make sure that the corner radius bounds are all color of the layerBG
        userMessage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        userMessage.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.937254902, green: 0.937254902, blue: 0.937254902, alpha: 1)
        

    }  
}
```

Chat View Controller

```
class ChatTableViewController: UIViewController {
    // Cell ID
    let cellId = "ReusableCell"
    
     // table view where chat bubbles will be displayed.
    @IBOutlet var chatBoxTableView: UITableView!
    
    // Set up the messages data structure to capture the chat client data
    var messages : [MessageData]?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        
        // set background color of the tableview
        chatBoxTableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9764705882, green: 0.9764705882, blue: 0.9764705882, alpha: 1)
        
        // register the custom cell xib file (previously nib file)
        chatBoxTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MessageCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        
        // remove separators
        chatBoxTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        chatBoxTableView.dataSource = self
        
        
        // call out chat client to fetch data from the
        ChatClient().getData { [weak self] (message) in
            self?.messages = message // initiate the messages data from the chat client
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.chatBoxTableView.reloadData() // reload the table to show it.
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
}

extension ChatTableViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        messages?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MessageCell

        
//         download image to display on the cell
        if let url = URL(string: messages?[indexPath.row].avatar_url ?? "Google.com") {
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data , _ , error in
                if let data = data, error == nil {
                    // on the main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)?.circleMask
                        self?.chatBoxTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("error data")
                }
            }.resume()
        }
        
        
        // give the cell data
        cell.userMessage.text = messages?[indexPath.row].message
        cell.userName.text = messages?[indexPath.row].name
        
        return cell

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image view that you have set the autolayout constraints on is called `userImage`.

```
class MessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
```

But you are setting the image into a *different* image view:

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)?.circleMask
```

That's not `userImage`, it's `imageView`. They are two different things.

Comment: I should also add that your entire method for downloading an image and adding it to the cell is completely wrong, and will lead to a lot of unnecessary downloading plus the images will appear in the wrong cell (or not at all, or you might crash). However, you can cross that bridge later. :)

Comment: Oh damn, thank you, I couldn't see that error I made. And yes I know the downloading method is wrong, I just did that to test the UI, I am planning to push that into the Chat Client and return a UI image into the model. Thank you for correcting me. Appreciate it.

Comment: "I just did that to test the UI" Perfectly reasonable, but if you are testing the UI you should _mock_ the network, not use the _real_ network. You'll want to arm yourself with some fake images for this purpose.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your guidance.